# customize the first rows of UITableview in SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to customize the first rows of UITableView.

I get data in JSON from API that has shops names and logo of the shops. 5 of the shops have a designed background and sould be bigger than the other cells on the top.

I can loop through the JSON and check if the shop has a design but what I couldnt yet do is:

append the shops with background design in array

make them appear first before the other shops without designs.

Here is an image of what I'm planning to do

[image]

[image: shops without]

Comment: You can use two cells and set a flag for two types of data to check which cell is to be used.

Comment: Can u explain more? what do u need exactly with code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your *Shop* class needs to have an optional property with background image, like:

```
class Shop {
   ...
   var backgroundImage: UIImage?
   ...
}
```

where only those 5 shops have background image, for the rest of them ***backgroundImage = nil***.

Assuming you have fetched and serialized the data from the server, let's begin from filtering the shops array and rearranging it's order:

```
//"fetchedShops" is array of serialized shops: [Shop]()
let shopsWithBackgroundImage = fetchedShops.filter( { $0.backgroundImg != nil } )
let showWithNoImage = shops.filter( { $0.backgroundImg == nil } 
let allShops = shopsWithBackgroundImage + showWithNoImage
```

Now, you have to create two different custom cells (as XIBs or in Storyboard) - the one with background and the one without. 
After that, just implement **cellForRowAtIndexPath** like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let shop = allShops[indexPath.row]
 if shop.backgroundImage != nil {
  //"shop" has background image - use custom cell with background image
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellWithBackgroundImageID, for: indexPath) as! CellWithBackground
  cell.backgroundImageView.image = shop.backgroundImage

  //other cell's config

  return cell
 }
 //"shop" has no backgroundImage - let's use normal cell
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: normalShopCellID, for: indexPath) as! NormalShopCell

 //other cell's config

 return cell
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks! how about `numberOfRowsInSection `? should I return the number of all shops ?

Comment: @leo0019 this is not necessary method

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Using approach I suggested, with table view with one section and 2 cell types - `numberOfRowsInSection` should equal `allShop.count`

Comment: Sorry last question. What if `backgroundImageView` is nill ? will the top cell be empty ? or the second cell covers the space of the backgroundImageView cell ?

Comment: `backgroundImageView` is just an `UIImageView` used for displaying an image.

When `backgroundImage`, which is `UIImage` type is `nil` ---> then the cell with no background image will be used.

Comment: so that means if there's no cell with background, the whole table view will be filled with basic cell ( second pic ) no empty space on the top

Comment: Exactly! No empty space :)

Comment: When I try to set a variable `let shopsWithBackgroundImage = fetchedShops.filter( { $0.backgroundImg != nil } )` I get error value of tuple string json has no member backgroundImg

Answer (score 1):

In Your tableview you use two cells. in this Two cells, one cell is bigger and set background image as u need. Use smaller cell in the second cell. Then you check the shop of design in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method. If Shop design is true then call First Cell or another in the else part of the function.

> The sample code...

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if self.design[indexPath.row] == true {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "firstCustomCell")
        //set the data here
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "thirdCustomCell")
        //set the data here
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: what if design is an empty array ?

Comment: @leo0019 When you get the response from the JSON you add the shop design. If you get response from shop design make it true other wise false